# Understanding a question in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, question-verification

I need help to understand a question in combinatorics.

> One corner square in a $3 \times 3$ grid is painted black, the other
> squares are white. In one move you can change color in all squares in
> a row or in a column. Can you get all the squares black after a number
> of such moves?
>
> Hint: Study the number of black squares among the four corner squares

Does this regard a Rubiks cube?  I cannot see other option that that, given the expression "in one move".

If not, any hints appreciated!

[[ Not looking for Solutions , only want Clarification on the Question ]]

Comment: Talking about Rubik's cubes, if you perform a permutation, like R, do those squares get black?

Comment: This is the definition of a "move". A "move" is changing the color of one row or one column. And then it is asking if you can achieve something by performing such moves. It could be called a "step" or "operation" instead of "move". It has nothing to do with any Rubik cube, it is about a square.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks, so if I change the colors of that row with the black square, it turns white and all the others in the row turn black.

Comment: Yes that would be right.

Comment: A reminder that this should be also tagged as contest-math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Planar Puzzle , not a Cubic Puzzle (Definitely not Rubic)

Putting in other words & Using Images may aid here , hence I will try that :

```
We have a 3×3 grid like given below  
One Corner Square in that is Initially painted Black.  
The other Squares are left White.  
Playing a game , you have 2 Possible moves :  
- you can change the colour in all Squares in a Selected row.  
- you can change the colour in all Squares in a Selected column.  

Aim of the game is to make the grid all Black.  
You can use these 2 moves in Succession.  
Can you get all the Squares Black after a number of such moves ?  
What is the Sequence of moves ?  

Hint: Study the number of Black Squares among the four corner Squares
```

No Colouring :
[image: 3x3]

Starting Position :
[image: 3x3]

Playing with the move to the top row :
[image: 3x3]

Ending Position :
[image: 3x3]

Solution :

```
Not Posting the Puzzle Solution.  
OP wants Puzzle Explanation , not Puzzle Solution.  

When OP responds , I may include that here.  

My HINT : There is Some Invariant which we can try to Identify.  
That Invariant will not change when making the moves.  
That Invariant is not there in the Ending Position.
```

Comment: Great illustration Prem. Thanks. I got a NO on this as answer.

Comment: Nice to know that it was useful , @Luthier415Hz , I was sure that you will not want the Solution & may want to think about it yourself !

Answer (score -4):

**Starting sequence:**

[X][][] 
[][][] 
[][][]

...

**Target sequence:**

[X][X][X] 
[X][X][X] 
[X][X][X]

**Solution:**

I think it is unsolvable as the starting position is already in a non-solvable state. It represents a planar graph.

> Prem's hint: Study the number of Black Squares among the four corner Squares

There is only 1 black square as a corner, it isn't solvable because of this principle.

> Prem's hint 2: There is Some Invariant which we can try to Identify.

> Prem's hint 3: That Invariant will not change when making the moves.

> Prem's hint 4: That Invariant is not there in the Ending Position.

The upper left square is what is invariant, it will inevitably transform into a white square.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think the answer to this question is No. PS: I didnt downvote your answer.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz No problem! Understood, the question was simply to answer if it regarded a Rubik's cube.